# Error in PHP code - Block Edumy moodle theme

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

I have the Edumy theme for Moodle, but when I installed it, on one of the course blocks (block_cocoon_course_enrl_c.php), I have two lines of code which are displaying the following errors on the right side.

[error Moodle Edumy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYRUk.png)

The code for those two lines is the following:

if (!empty($this->content->add_to_cart_link) && !empty($this->content->add_to_cart_text)) {
$this->content->text .= ' content->add_to_cart_link . '">' . $this->content->add_to_cart_text . '';
}

if (!empty($this->content->buy_now_link) && !empty($this->content->buy_now_text)) {
$this->content->text .= 'content->buy_now_link . '">' . $this->content->buy_now_text . '';
}

If someone could help me out, I'd truly appreciate it.

I've tried to remove the single and double quotes, but didn't have any success.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it's open source, so I can't see the code

But I'm guessing you have the url in both the add to cart text and add to cart link in the block? Try replacing the add to cart text with "Add to cart" or something

Maybe contact Cocoon directly for support

https://me.createdbycocoon.com/